# RAID array rebuilt no longer mounts -- isw_ *randchars*_STRIPE changed

Tags: mount, raid, fstab

I have a RAID 5 system, ICH10R, on a eVGA classified x58 motherboard. The RAID failed because of an application failure in Windows 7 (dual boot) which forced a hard restart.

I rebuilt the array using the Intel Matrox Storage Manager app in Windows 7 (all automatic), but now the random characters changed and my drives won't mount. Basically the random prefix changed and now Kubuntu doesn't know where to look. I have labeled the volume "STRIPE" and it had:

/dev/mapper/isw_bedfeijgaj_STRIPE#

where # is the number of my partition. Now the device shows up as:

/dev/mapper/isw_bedfhcecfj_STRIPE#

so I had to change all of the entries in /etc/fstab. The reason for my asking here is two fold:

1. Would there (by default) be any other places where the device would be listed explicitly & I should change it?
2. Is there approach I could've taken so that the characters wouldn't be random and wouldn't change after a rebuild?  Specifically, I had to [go through hell] (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/parted/+bug/568050) just to get the system to boot.  So I've already exhausted my googling skills, just curious if anyone knows of unpublished settings or things I may have missed?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is recommended to always refer to filesystems by their UUID, instead of their `/dev` path, which may change, based on driver, timing, etc. To get the UUID, use `blkid`:

```
sudo blkid /dev/mapper/isw_bedfhcecfj_STRIPE#
```

Then replace `/dev/mapper/isw_bedfhcecfj_STRIPE#` in `/etc/fstab` with `UUID=...what blkid reported for uuid...`

Comment: Excellent.  Worked like a charm.  Thanks!  (And sorry it took me so long to accept your answer).